# Looking for Erlang Q&A platforms/communities

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, beam

I am looking for Erlang Q&A platforms/communities for discussion and clarification. I use StackOverflow & erlangforums.com as of now. Both communities are great. Are there any additional Q&A platforms?

I have checked the following sites which maintain Erlang bookmarks. But I did not find any additional Q&A platforms.

1. https://github.com/drobakowski/awesome-erlang#Erlang-reading
2. http://spawnedshelter.com/
3. https://github.com/0xAX/erlang-bookmarks/blob/master/ErlangBookmarks.md
4. http://www.planeterlang.com/

It is unfortunate that the Q&A platform [erlang-questions](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/) is brought down after being active for the last 25 years. Also, I did not find any way to search through the old posts based on keywords across different months in one go. Is there a way to search on this platform?

Comment: There are some resources listed at https://www.erlang.org/community . Perhaps the Slack team might be what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks @legoscia. I have joined Slack. Let me explore it.

Comment: I will update this post as I find new communities. 

1) https://exercism.org/tracks/erlang for coding exercises

Answer (score 1):

The replacement for erlang-questions is the new forum [Erlang Forums](https://erlangforums.com/).[1](https://groups.google.com/g/erlang-programming/c/WOOMy5-tUnE) It is free to register and can you login using GitHub.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @2240. I have been extensively using https://erlangforums.com/